# Apollo InMemoryCache Performance Strategies for Large Data Set (React)

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo

The initial data set received from an Apollo Client GraphqQL query for an application I am trying to tune is currently very large. In "large" I mean that it seems that the data normalizes to about 7,000 entries under the "data" key in the cache. The payload is about 1.6MB. If I were to save the cache's data entry it's normalized to about 3MB. I'm not a fan of how the initial query works as I am currently redesigning their application to use cursors, and filtering, on the graph rather than the client fetching such a large amount of data and filtering itself. The current implementation cannot scale due to larger data sets will be returned when this software is installed in other locations. But, I am looking for a short term solution to make this cache build faster while I undertake very large redesign task.

*UPDATE July 25, 2018** The cursor approach doesn't work as the cache write performance degrades as more entries are added during each page/cursor of data is fetch.

The real issue is that IE 11, which we I have to support due to the industry's (healthcare) usage of this browser, is extremely slow. It's very difficult to measure, but it's about 8-10x slower than Chrome in the area of the Apollo cache and react integration code. Chrome can take 1-2 seconds to build the cache on these slower virtual desktops while IE will take 10-20 seconds.

So, my question is: Are there any performance tweaks to help the cache build faster? I've attached a screenshot to show where the bottleneck lies. It's the same in chrome as in IE, it's just about an order of magnitude slower in IE. I'm not sure if it's an IE shortcoming, or if it's some crazy polyfill issue that is awful. The screenshot shows the hot spots that show up in the performance results. Yes, this screenshot is of the development version of React, but we aren't seeing any real noticeable performance increases in a production. The screenshot is really just a call to the graph and the simplest HTML table being rendered with about 260 rows. The render phase is negligible. It seems there are an awful lot of queued up events or 'work' during this phase. Perhaps there is a way to suspend this? Chrome's profiler shows the same hot spot, it's just not as slow.

Anyway, any advice is greatly appreciated.

The screenshot columns are: function | invocation count | time (seconds)

[image: IE11 performance screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Our team is facing similar issues. Our current approach is to "denormalize" part of server schema into a String type, which holds a JSON string. On the client side, we will parse the JSON string that's returned by the Apollo client.

Comment: How this approach is working for you now?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem (on Apollo client 3.3.6). Eventually, it became clear that a collection this large was not suitable for the Apollo client cache. Rather than saddle yourself with seconds-long processing (probably right when you load your app), I'd strongly recommend that you manage your larger datasets on your own outside the cache - native js map/filter/etc is much faster and probably a better fit depending on why you need the data. Just pass the option `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`, and watch your app speed up significantly. Any large fetch (thousands of typed results) is probably better off with this treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo 3.0 will have an option to disable cache normalization for a type:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/caching/cache-configuration/#disabling-normalization